# Geotagged photographs hosted on website and shared via KML

Tags: kml, geotag

I have a database of about 500 geotagged photographs that I would like to host on my personal website, and then share as a KML to other users. They would get a relatively small KML file size (~1-2 MB) with placemarkers of each photo and thumbnails. When you click the thumbnail the path would direct it to the webpage to pull up the full photo in a browser. I have access to Google Earth, Arcmap 10.2, Matlab, etc. Seems Python would be the ideal tool for this but I don't have much experience there. Can anyone point me to the general steps I would need to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to generate your own KML, and the best solution for you obviously depends on which software you like to use, and which languages you have experience with (Python is a good option... check out pykml). The general steps would be to generate the set of thumbnails, extract a list of point locations (lat/longs) from your photo locations (maybe use gdalinfo?), and then generate a KML which creates the point Placemarks and populates the description balloons with the thumbnail and a link to the full image on your site.

Alternatively, you can easily put an album of photos on a map with Google Photos and Google MyMaps (https://mymaps.google.com).  First create an album in Google Photos. Then create a new Google MyMap, under a new Layer, click the import button, select the "Photo Albums" tab and then select your album. Once you have created the map, it can easily be embedded on your website.